# Debugging PySerial? Log to stdio?

Tags: python, pyserial

Does pySerial provide a logging option for all serial port communications to be logged onto stdio?

I have code like this:

```
    with serial.Serial('COM62', 921600) as mcu:
        mcu.write('r\r\n')
```

and I would like to see all the data exchanges happening back and forward

Comment: This is a difficult one. No, PySerial itself does not include a logging facility, although it would be possible to create a wrapper class, which does the logging. One would have to create a new buffer for the program to read and let the logger start a new thread for asynchronous data handling. Maintaining _pyserial_'s timeout handling and other flow control would be quite difficult.

Comment: Creating a wrapper which logs everything you write and _actually read_ from the serial port would be much easier, though. Is this what you're looking for?